# How to assign out parameter in function?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a method that returns an object and also has an out parameter.  The method calls another method that takes in the same out paramter as another out paramter.  This gives a build error on the return statement:

> The out parameter 'param1' must be assigned to before control leaves
>   the current method

The code looks like:

```
public TypeA Method1(TypeA param1, out bool param2)
{
  /... some logic here .../
  SubMethod(out param2);
  /... some logic here .../
  return param1;
}
```

param2 is manipulated in SubMethod(), not in Method1().  Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: That code does not agree with the error message. Try to isolate it to *just* code with `param1` (I think `param2` is a red herring here).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I think too.

Comment: Whats the relation between TypeA and TypeB?

Comment: Sheesh.  What a nightmare.  To answer your question, just assign a value to your `out` parameter, just like you would any other variable.  Whatever logic this code is supposed to implement, somewhere you need to say `param2 = (some boolean value)`  That's it.

Comment: The code is a little confusing.  Why are you returning param1 of TypeB, when your return type should be TypeA?

Comment: @LucasB: that's why I suspect there is more going on than we've been given to work from.

Comment: Don't introduce a dummy assignment of `param2` if there's a risk you don't understand the program flow. Are you sure `SubMethod` will **always** be called before a `return` statement is reached? Is there some `return` statement earlier, or is the `SubMethod` call inside an `if` block or something like that?

Comment: @LucasB: Should have been TypeA.  I've fixed it.  Jeppe - there are some conditionals in the logic part and maybe that is why I get the error.  I'll have to go through that area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, I will assign a 'default' value. Regardless of bool, int, myFoo, etc. - set a default value.

```
public TypeA Method1(TypeB param1, out bool param2)
{
  param2 = false;   // default value;
  // or
  param2 = default(bool); // in cases where you are not sure what the default is

  /... some logic here .../
  SubMethod(out param2);
  /... some logic here .../
  return param1; // UPDATE: <- this is where you are receiving the exception
}
```

But you need to identify why the exception refers to 'param1' when param1 is clearly not at fault in this example ( *for clarification* : **assuming `TypeB : TypeA`** and is properly constrained).

I believe that passing `param2` as an `out` parameter in `SubMethod(...)` removes the obligation to assign `param2`. However, you have not assigned anything to `param1`. Is there more going on here that has not been explained?

Comment: I think you nailed it on the head.  The issue is because he is returning a TypeB when it requires TypeA.

Comment: I think just assigning at the beginning is what I'm left with.  There is other stuff going on (conditionals) that might be creating code paths for SubMethod(), which are not taken.

Comment: Like I said in the comment to question, be careful not to assign `param2 = false;` unless you accept that `Method1` might return with `param2` set to that value. Does `false` make sense as an acceptable value if `SubMethod` is never hit? If the compiler can see that every code path goes through the `SubMethod(out param2)` call, it will not be necessary to set `param2` to some meaningless value first. (`param2` is definitely assigned after `SubMethod` returns.)

Answer (score 1):

You could set it to `false` at the very beginning of `Method1`.

Comment: How 'bout a little explanation?

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest moving the out parameter in SubMethod to the return type:

```
public TypeA Method1(TypeB param1, out bool param2)
{
  /... some logic here .../
  param2 = SubMethod(param2);
  /... some logic here .../
  return param1;
}
```